# emulator out of window non movable windows 8.Always have to change the monitor resolution.. need permanent solution

Tags: android, emulation, genymotion

I am working with android studio 1.2 and genymotion emulator. whenever I am opening the emulator it is displaying results but moving out of screen. after changing the screen resolution to lower and reseting back worked, i got the complete screen of emulator. But I need to do it again and again whenever I start it. Can any one give me permanent solution. I also tried windows.x=0,windows.y=0 and also tried to change RAM size to lower nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

While Starting the emulator, this dialog will appear, select your own custom size for your emulator like this. I have selected 4 inches.[image]